# ¿Como hacer que varios hilos pueden acceder a la lista de lectura, si ningún subproceso lo está modificando?

Tags: java, hilos

Creo una clase MySafeList desde la implementación no segura para subprocesos de java.util.ArrayList  y quiero que sea segura para subprocesos.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MySafeList extends ArrayList<Double>{

    static ArrayList<Double> mySafeList;

    public boolean add(Double d){
        mySafeList.add(d);
        return true;
    }

    public int size(){
        return mySafeList.size();
    }

    public Double get(int i){
        return mySafeList.get(i);

    }

    static boolean stressTest(int n, int m){
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[n]; //El nombre de tu variable se llama "threads"
        try{
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
                threads[i].start();
                for(int j=0; j<m;j++){
                    Double d = new Double((double) j);
                    mySafeList.add(d);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySafeList safeList = new MySafeList();
        stressTest(2,4);    
    }

}
```

¿Como hacer que varios subprocesos pueden acceder a la lista de lectura, si ningún subproceso lo está modificando?

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple puede ser utilizar un wrapper sincronizado de la lista `mySafeList`. Para obtenerlo puedes utilizar uno de los métodos que ofrece la clase `Collections`.

```
static List<Double> mySafeList = Collections.synchronizedList​(new ArrayList());
```

De este modo la lista `mySafeList` si es thread-safe por lo que puede ser manipulada por varios hilos simultáneamente.

OJO: Esto tiene sus restricciones si quieres recorrer la lista, por ejemplo, con un iterador, ya que tienes que utilizar bloques `synchronized`.

Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo al JavaDoc de la clase [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html).

El paquete `java.util.concurrent` brinda otro tipo de colecciones, muy interesantes, preparadas para otros escenarios de acceso concurrente (ej. productor-consumidor).